# Table form serialize is not working after sorting tr

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This my table data in html format:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <form id="filterForm">
        </form>
    </thead>
    <form id="studentsForm">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="sorted">
                <td><span class="selected">WAHEED</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sorted">
                <td><span class="selected">DON</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sorted">
                <td><span class="rejected">JACK</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sorted">
                <td><span class="selected">MARK</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sorted">
                <td><span class="rejected">GATEES</span</td></tr>
      </tbody>
    </form>
</table>
```

This is the sorting javascript after ajax filter response.

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr.sorted');
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (rows[i].querySelector('span.rejected')) {
        rows[i].closest('tbody').appendChild(rows[i]);
    }
}
```

SO when the sorting is done the students will be like this all selected on top and not selected on the bottom:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="selected">WAHEED</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="selected">MARK</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="selected">DON</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="rejected">JACK</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="rejected">GATEES</span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My issue is when i submit the form data with out soring the data is going fine But when i submit the form with Sort it the serialize of form is not working inside the for i have this feild for every `<tr>`

```
<input type="text" class="overrideStudentcomment"  name="comment[<?php echo $gdScoreData['student_pid']; ?>]">
```

I think there is an issue in sorting unable to rectify it. may be the append is being done out side of form 
can anyone help me out..?

Comment: is your `input` is inside `form` tag?

Comment: yes but after sorting i think it is appending outside of the form can u check it once..?

Comment: You can't think you have to be sure. Can you please add code after appending how your HTML is made!

Comment: after appenind how can i see the html code when i click view source it is showing that data which is present before append.it is showing something like this in firebug `html` inside `tbody` `<form id="studentsForm"></form>`

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't use **form** inside a table beacuse it will not work. If i want to redirect me somewhere I use the **a** tag.

**Example:**

```
    @foreach($data as $card)
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <td>{{ $card -> id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $card -> cardType }}</td>
            <td>{{ $card -> cardValue }} RON</td>
            <td>{{ $card -> createdBy }}</td>
            <td>{{ $card -> created_at }}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="to somewhere">
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>                       
                </form>
            </td>
    @endforeach
```

Instead of this, use this :

```
   @foreach($data as $card)
        <tr style="text-align: center;">
            <td>{{ $card -> id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $card -> cardType }}</td>
            <td>{{ $card -> cardValue }} RON</td>
            <td>{{ $card -> createdBy }}</td>
            <td>{{ $card -> created_at }}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="icon pencil-lg-icon" href="{{ route ( 'admin.catalog.giftcards.edit', $card->id ) }}" style="color: white; padding: 8px 10px;"></a>
                <a class="icon trash-icon" href="{{ route ( 'admin.catalog.giftcards.delete', $card->id ) }}" style="color: white; padding: 8px 10px;"></a>
            </td>
    @endforeach
```

Or you can try this

```
 @foreach($data as $card)

    // Outside the table
    <form action="to somewhere" id="idform"></form>

    <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <td>{{ $card -> id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $card -> cardType }}</td>
        <td>{{ $card -> cardValue }} RON</td>
        <td>{{ $card -> createdBy }}</td>
        <td>{{ $card -> created_at }}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" form="idform">Submit</button>         
        </td>
@endforeach
```

I hope i helped you.

Comment: While the form's location in the HTML is invalid… the question is about sorting data with JavaScript. Your answer doesn't address the problem at all.